# Problemas para instalar el Laravel Websockets

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

Pues mira intento instalar el Laravel Websockets , pero da estos problemas

```
composer require beyondcode/laravel-websockets
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update beyondcode/laravel-websockets
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires guzzlehttp/psr7 ^1.5, found guzzlehttp/psr7[1.5.0, ..., 1.9.1] but the package is fixed to 2.6.2 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
  Problem 2
    - Root composer.json requires pusher/pusher-php-server ^5.0, found pusher/pusher-php-server[v5.0.0, v5.0.1, 5.0.2, 5.0.3] but the package is fixed to 7.2.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
  Problem 3
    - beyondcode/laravel-websockets[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.2.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - beyondcode/laravel-websockets[1.4.0, ..., 1.10.0, 2.0.0-beta.1, ..., 2.0.0-beta.29] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.2.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - beyondcode/laravel-websockets[1.11.0, ..., 1.13.0, 2.0.0-beta.28, ..., 2.0.0-beta.36] require guzzlehttp/psr7 ^1.5 -> found guzzlehttp/psr7[1.5.0, ..., 1.9.1] but the package is fixed to 2.6.2 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - beyondcode/laravel-websockets[1.13.1, ..., 1.13.2] require illuminate/broadcasting ^6.0|^7.0|^8.0|^9.0 -> found illuminate/broadcasting[v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., v9.52.16] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - react/http[v1.1.0, ..., v1.9.0] require psr/http-message ^1.0 -> found psr/http-message[1.0, 1.0.1, 1.1] but the package is fixed to 2.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - beyondcode/laravel-websockets 2.0.0-beta.37 requires illuminate/broadcasting ^6.3|^7.0|^8.0|^9.0 -> found illuminate/broadcasting[v6.3.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., v9.52.16] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - beyondcode/laravel-websockets[1.14.0, ..., 1.14.1] require react/http ^1.1 -> satisfiable by react/http[v1.1.0, ..., v1.9.0].
    - Root composer.json requires beyondcode/laravel-websockets * -> satisfiable by beyondcode/laravel-websockets[1.0.0, ..., 1.14.1, 2.0.0-beta.1, ..., 2.0.0-beta.37].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require beyondcode/laravel-websockets:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require beyondcode/laravel-websockets:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
henry@debian:~/Escritorio/SportBuddy$
```

He bajado las versiones y todo

```
"php": "^8.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.8",
        "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.5",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
        "livewire/livewire": "^3.3",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^5.0",
        "beyondcode/laravel-websockets": "^2.0"
```

Usando los comandos

```
composer require guzzlehttp/psr7:^2.0 --ignore-platform-reqs

composer require pusher/pusher-php-server:^7.0 --ignore-platform-reqs

composer require beyondcode/laravel-websockets:^2.0 --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Pero nada sigue sin funcionar alguna solucion o alternativa? Es para poder instalar un chat en vivo. Ya que es para lo unico que lo necesito esto. LLevo ya varios dias con estos problemas

Comment: pero si te da las opciones a utilizar y los comandos solo debes leer :V as intentado pasar el texto por un traductor?

Comment: Pues dime cual es el comando? porque por mas que he probado no funciona ninguno de los que aparece ahi por eso te digo :)

Comment: paselo por el traductor y vera de lo que hablo....
para ser desarrollador lo primero es aprender a leer e investigar, y dice claramente que tu version de php no coincide con la version requerida y te da algunos comandos y a su vez te indica que debes hacer un downupgrade!
adional si vas al repositorio vez que no se esta actualizando!

Comment: Solucionado , use el comando
```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install php
```

Y ya me dejo instalar el websocket
```
composer require beyondcode/laravel-websockets -W